# Is Jedha based on Jeddah?

Tags: star-wars

In *Rogue One*, a prominent setting is the city (or moon, in keeping with *Star Wars* naming conventions) of Jedha, a place sacred to the Jedi and to people of various faiths who worship the Force.

> I ask you to believe that Jedha is a nexus for faith, life, and the
> Force of Others in all their forms. If the Force can be embodied in a
> vision or a living creature, why not a place? Or why not an idea? Why
> can pilgrimage not be Jedha, and Jedha not be the Force?
>
> <sub>*Rogue One*</sub>

At first I thought that Jedha must have been derived in a very obvious manner from Jedi. Until I saw the [Wikipedia page for the Saudi Arabian city of Jeddah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeddah):

> Jeddah is the principal gateway to Mecca, Islam’s holiest city, which
> able-bodied Muslims are required to visit at least once in their
> lifetime. It is also a gateway to Medina, the second holiest place in
> Islam.

The name is pretty similar, and it has the same nature as a holy site. Has there ever been any confirmaton that Jeddah inspired Jedha?

Comment: SW has a penchant for naming planets after north african cities:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tataouine

Comment: I think the name Jeddha was supposed to look like the origin of the word Jedi.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't found any mention that it is named directly after Jeddah.

However Gareth Edwards has stated that he set Jedha on a desert planet as [he was trying to evoke a Jerusalem or Mecca feel about the location](http://www.mtv.com/news/2906063/rogue-one-gareth-edwards-jedha-jedi/).

> *"If A New Hope is kind of like the story of Jesus, there must be a whole religion beyond that," he said. "We felt like, for 1,000 generations, the Jedi were kind of these leaders of the spiritual belief system. It's got to be **like a Mecca or a Jerusalem**, but in the Star Wars world.*
>
> <sub>***Gareth Edwards - Director of Rogue One***</sub>

So no direct confirmation of Jeddah directly being inspiration, but it is pretty close in as much as Mecca itself, along with Jerusalem, served as inspiration and a basis for Jedha in Rogue One.

<sub>***Taken from part of my answer given to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153481/whats-with-all-the-tatooine-deserts-in-star-wars/153494#153494)***</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Building on to Cearon O'Flynn's answer, while there is no direct confirmation, I think there definitely is an indirect link concerning the inspiration material.

[A lot of elements in Star Wars are based on Frank Herbert's Dune](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sources_and_analogues) which was published in 1965 ([and widely regarded as having influenced many science fiction works](https://www.fandom.com/articles/dune-influence-sci-fi-movies)). Tatooine and Jedha are similar to the Arrakis desert planet, sand worms on Tatooine are similar to Shai Hulud, spice on Kessel is similar to Melange, and there are even similarities between elements of Jedi and Fremen religion or culture; The Chosen One to bring balance to the Force (Anakin) is somewhat a watered down version of Dune's Mahdi (المهدي), a messianic figure prophesied to appear in order save the Fremen.

It's well-known that Dune is heavily inspired by Islam and the Arabic language. It would be natural that Star Wars, like it's predecessor and source inspiration material, borrows elements of spirituality, religion and pilgrimage, especially from Islam as it's the most mysterious and least well understood among Western viewers (it's main target audience).

Comment: This seems to be very opinion-based. Can you offer any evidence to back up these bold assertions?

Comment: "Dune — widely regarded as the "parent" of science fiction, having been published in 1965. " What?  Science fiction existed for **decades** before *Dune* was published.  [Lucas himself acknowledges influences from *Dune*, but also from the scifi serials that ran in movie theaters in the 1930s - as well as many other sources.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sources_and_analogues)

Comment: Too much chatbot in this answer.

Comment: There are sand worms on Tatooine?

Comment: @Shawn:  The idea of the sarlacc could come from sand worms.

Comment: @JRE I might have been too opinionated here, but that actually does support the claim in the answer, no?

Comment: @Shawn That's just a myth, although people who walk rhythm on the sand dunes are never seen again...

Comment: @Erfan:  The link says that *Dune* was one of **many** things that influenced *Star Wars.*  It does not support the notion that "Dune is tha parent of science fiction."

Comment: @JRE fair enough — I've made the statement less strong, and added sources :)